# Form Panels Resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, panel

How to resize panels inside a form accordingly?

My form has 3 panels

[image: Form with 3 panels]

If I set panel2.visible to false, panel3 occupies the space.

[image: Panel3 to panel2]

If I set panel1.visible to false, panel3 also occupies the rest.

[image: panel3 to panel1 and 2]

Going back to original form - all 3 panels are present.

If I set panel1.visible to false, panel2 and 3 occupies the space of panel1

[image: panel2 and 3 to panel1]

Once panels 1 or 2 are visible again, panel 3 will go back the way it was.

Comment: Do you have some code to show what approach you have taken to solve this problem?

Comment: . I don't think just a few properties or containers will suffice. You will have to write code for that. Use the `VisibleChanged` event!

Comment: @Steve no code yet but I've tried dock and anchor properties but no luck :-(

Comment: @Taw I'll try to look on that too.

Comment: Can you give me more information about your problem? I use splitContainer and have no problem

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi hmm I haven't used splitContainer but I could explore on that.I have 3 panels in a form as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that as per your cases in  question. Panel1 will be always on top even when panel 2 and 3 are hidden.
In same way panel 2 will be always left aligned. Panel 3 will be always occupy available space .

Please set dock properties on panel control.

```
Panel1.Dock = top
Panel2.Dock = left
Panel3.Dock = fill
```

One more thing when controls are hidden make their sizes as 0. And When visible set sizes to default.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ANaik, I'll try this one.

Comment: It worked! I thought I need a lot of code to do that. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

Just an addt'l info, It seems tablelayout has a potential solution to my problem but I like @ANaik solution more.

```
            if (myPanel.Visible)
            {
                myPanel.Visible = false;

                tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(myPanel, new 
                TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 1));
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(myPanel, 2);

            }
            else
            {
                myPanel.Visible = true;

                tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(myPanel, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 1));
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(myPanel, 1);
            }
```